# Laravel vuejs spa axios auth scaffolding

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

I built an laravel vue spa application and would like to add a login, I ran `php artisan make:auth` to create an auth scaffolding. I am trying to call the login route using axios, but it keeps returning success even if the user does not exists(I manually added a user to the database).

This is the login component:

```
<template>
    <v-card class="elevation-12">
        <v-container
            fluid
            grid-list-md
        >
            <v-card-text>
                <v-form>
                    <v-text-field 
                        box
                        name="login" 
                        label="Login" 
                        type="text"
                        v-model="email">
                    </v-text-field>
                    <v-text-field 
                        box
                        name="password" 
                        label="Password" 
                        id="password" 
                        type="password"
                        v-model="password">
                    </v-text-field>
                </v-form>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions class="card-pb-1">
                <v-btn 
                    @click="login">Login</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-container>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script>

export default {

    props: {
        source: String
    },

    data: () => ({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        remember: ''
    }),

    methods: {
        getLoginData () {
            return {
                email: this.email, 
                password: this.password
            };
        },

        login() {
            axios.post("/login", this.getLoginData())
                .then(response => {         
                    console.log("success");
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log("error");
                })
        }
    }

};
</script>
```